# Can you explain which word is connected to the word 'left'? What is the grammatical construct of the bold?

Tags: verbs, clauses, subjects

I am trying to understand the bold part of this quote from "[Sky-high house prices in the most desirable cities are holding back growth and jobs](http://www.economist.com/news/special-report/21621157-sky-high-house-prices-most-desirable-cities-are-holding-back-growth-and-jobs-home)":

> As transport costs started to fall at the beginning of the 20th century, many of **the manufacturing firms clustered in cities in developed countries left in search** of cheaper land and labour.

- Which word is connected to the word "left"?
- Who left?  The "developed countries", or "the manufacturing firms"?
- The word "left" is after "countries".  How can you know the "firms" left?
- What tenses are involved? "firms clustered" and "developed countries that left" suggest past tense.

Comment: are developed countries the one who left or are they the firms?

Comment: The manufacturing firms left. (manufacturing firms -> from developed countries). They (the manufacturing firms) searched for cheaper land, and labour.

Comment: but the word 'left' is after countries,how do you know it's the firms?

Comment: can't this be in past?'they clustered' and 'developed countries that left'.

Comment: I think it is best that you ask this (**can't this be in past?'they clustered' and 'developed countries that left'**) in a separate question to avoid multiple subjects under one question. :)

Comment: @tbp - We know that the firms left for a few reasons.  For one, it doesn't make sense for a country to leave!  How does a country leave in search of cheaper land?  What is it leaving, itself?   Secondly, if the firms clustered and the countries left, we would have to write "the firms clustered in cities in developed countries **that** left".  But I agree that this sentence is a little tricky for a new learner.

Comment: @stangdon -- There are historical examples of countries leaving a place (sometimes with valuable land) and moving to a place with cheaper land.  Usually they were forced to move by an expanding society.  Consider the histories of Oklahoma and Deseret.  There are classical and medieval examples, as well.

Comment: @Jasper - I would call those "peoples" or "nations", not "countries", since "country", in most usages, implies an independent sovereign state with a particular geographical area.

Comment: @stangdon -- Yes. They were "peoples" or "nations" with organized governments in particular geographical areas, who moved their entire societies -- including reestablishing governments with new particular geographical areas. Their "independence" and "sovereignty" could be quibbled with, much the way Mexico quibbled with Texas' independence and sovereignty at about the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As transport costs started to fall at the beginning of the 20th century, many of **the manufacturing firms clustered in cities in developed countries left in search** of cheaper land and labour.

**Many of the firms left.**  ("Many" = subject; "of" = preposition; "the" = definite article, which is a kind of determiner; "firms" = noun, the superset that the subject is part of; "of the firms" = prepositional phrase acting as an adjective; "left" = verb)

What kind of firms?  **Manufacturing** firms.  ("Manufacturing" is a gerund acting like an adjective.)

How were the "manufacturing firms" organized?  They were **clustered**.  ("Clustered" is a past-participle at the head of an adjectival phrase.)

Where were the "manufacturing firms clustered"?  They were **in cities**.  ("in" is a preposition; "in cities" is a prepositional phrase that acts as an adverb.)

Where were the "cities" the "manufacturing firms clustered in"?  They were **in developed countries**.  ("in" is a preposition; "developed" is a past-participle that describes "countries"; "countries" is a noun; "in developed countries" is a prepositional phrase that acts as an adjective.)

Why did "the firms" leave?  They were "**in search of**" <something>.  ("in" = preposition; "search" = noun form of a verb; "of" <something> = prepositional phrase that completes the idiom; the whole phrase acts as an adverb.)

What were "the firms" seeking?  They were "in search of" **cheaper land and labour.**  ("land" = object; "cheaper" = comparative adjective describing both "land" and "labour"; "labour" = "object"; "and" = conjunction; "land and labour" = compound object; "of cheaper land and labour" = prepositional phrase that acts as an adverb.)

What is the "cheapness" of the "land and labour" being compared to?  It is implied that the cost "of land and labour" (in the places the firms moved to) was cheaper than the cost "of land and labour" (in the places the firms moved from).

Answer (score 1):

The subject is 'firms' - the phrase 'clustered in cities in developed countries' clarifies which firms are being discussed. If you remove that phrase you can see the subject-verb relationship more easily:

"...many of the manufacturing firms...left in search of cheaper land and labour."

Comment: @tbp, you may refer to this, and in addition, the line, "clustered in cities in developed countries" modify the 'manufacturing firms'.