# Combining two questions with "or"

Tags: questions, conjunctions, pronouns

I have these two questions:

> Are developed countries the one who left? Are the firms the one who left?"

I want to combine them using "or". Is this correct:

> Are developed countries the one who left or are they the firms?

Also, it is correct to use "who" in this way?

Comment: Welcome to our community! To keep the quality of the questions high, we do not answer proofreading requests. Unfortunately, the way your question is currently formulated, raises the alarms of being such question. To make it on-topic, you need to tell us what confuses you. For more info, please see [Alternative websites for proofreading](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/263/) and [Details, please!](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/439/).

Comment: i want to ask  someone this question .i do not know how to express it correctly.

Comment: Well, which part do you think is correct? Which part is doubtful? (And if you can explain, why?)

Comment: "are developed countries the one who left? are the firms the one who left?" i want to combine them using 'or'. and is the word 'who' correct?

Comment: @tbp - Now that we know what you're asking about, I've reopened the question.

Comment: The example questions discuss the example quote in http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74414

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be as simple as joining the two questions with "or":

**Are the developed countries the ones that left, or are the firms the ones that left?**

That is a perfectly decent, unremarkable sentence all by itself.

Your original sentence,

> <strike>Are developed countries the one who left or are they the firms?</strike>

is not really correct because the "they" sounds like it refers to the developed countries, which is not what you mean - this sentence sounds like "Are the developed countries the ones who left?  Or are developed countries the firms?"

**One vs Ones:** It has to be "ones", not "one", because "countries" and "firms" are plural, so we have to use the plural "ones", not the singular "one".

**Who vs That:** Usually, "who" is for people and "that" for objects.  [Some resources say that groups of people, like countries, should be referred to with "that"](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoVwhVt.asp), but you will also find [resources that say groups of people can be referred to with "who"](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Pronouns/faq0007.html).  In informal speech, "who" is fine, since both countries and firms are groups of people.

**Other possibilities:** If you really want to phrase it a different way, other possibilities are

**Were the developed countries the ones who left, or was it the firms?**
**Did the developed countries leave, or did the firms?**
**Which ones left, the developed countries or the firms?**

Comment: I am very confused about the meaning of this sentence!!!! developed countries left?!! the ones that left?!!! or the firms? what do these mean?! it is the strangest sentence I ever heard in English!

Comment: @Ahmad - You will probably understand the question better if you read tbp's original question about the context: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74414/can-you-explain-which-word-is-connected-to-the-word-left-what-is-the-grammati

Comment: Thank you, yeah without that post, it was hard to guess what the sentence speak about. Now, I know that "the firms left in search of cheaper labor", but what still "leave" means for "firms"?